# Returning Beginning and Ending Row Numbers With Matching Values Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have a table with Ticker Symbols (A), workdays over the course of a year (B), opening value (C), high value (D), low value (E), closing value (F), and volume (E). The data is chronological by workday and alphabetical by Ticker Symbol.

I am trying to create in the second sub a command that pulls the first and last row numbers with matching ticker symbols. Then using those row numbers, pull the corresponding opening and closing values for the year to create a yearly change column. I don't get any errors from my code, but the yearly change is not pulling the correct value. What am I missing?

```
Sub TickerVolume()

    ' Set an initial variable for holding the ticker
    Dim Ticker As String 

    'Create new column headers
    Cells(1, 9).Value = "Ticker"
    Cells(1, 10).Value = "Yearly Change"
    Cells(1, 11).Value = "Percent Change"
    Cells(1, 12).Value = "Total Stock Volume"

    ' Set an initial variable for holding the volume total 
    Dim Vol_Total As Double
    Vol_Total = 0

    ' Keep track of the location for summary table
    Dim Summary_Table_Row As Integer
    Summary_Table_Row = 2
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through all tickers
    For i = 2 To LastRow

    ' Check if we are still within the same ticker, if it is not...
    If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 1).Value Then

      ' Set the Ticker
      Ticker = Cells(i, 1).Value

      ' Add to the Volume Total
      Vol_Total = Vol_Total + Cells(i, 7).Value

      ' Print the Ticker in the Summary Table
      Range("I" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Ticker

      ' Print the Vol to the Summary Table
      Range("L" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Vol_Total

      ' Add one to the summary table row for next ticker
      Summary_Table_Row = Summary_Table_Row + 1

      ' Reset the Vol Total
      Vol_Total = 0

    ' If the cell immediately following a row is the same Ticker...
    Else

      ' Add to the Ticker Total
      Vol_Total = Vol_Total + Cells(i, 7).Value

    End If

    Next i

End Sub

Sub YearlyChange()

    ' Find start and end rows with unique Ticker
    Dim TickStartRow As Long
    Dim TickEndRow As Long
    Dim Summary_Table_Row As Integer
    Summary_Table_Row = 2
    LastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through all tickers
    For i = 2 To LastRow1

      'Find start and end rows
      TickStartRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Cells(i, 9), after:=Cells(1, 
      1)).Row
      TickEndRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Cells(i, 9), after:=Cells(1, 1), 
      SearchDirection:=xlPreivous).Row

      ' Print the Change in the Summary Table
      Range("J" & Summary_Table_Row).Value = Range("C" & TickStartRow).Value - 
      Range("F" & TickEndRow).Value

      ' Add one to the summary table row for next ticker
      Summary_Table_Row = Summary_Table_Row + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm failing to see how the value of *Summary_Table_Row * is passed back and forth between subs. It is declared in TickerVolume but not passed byRef to YearlyChange.

Comment: I had it changed in my code but forgot to update when I typed the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably that in

```
TickEndRow = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Cells(i, 9), after:=Cells(1, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPreivous).Row
```

you've spelled `xlPrevious` incorrectly and without `Option Explicit` the compiler is just assuming an empty variable for what you've called `xlPreivous`. Adding `Option Explicit` to the top of your module code will help catch small typo errors like this. Try correcting that and see what you get.

Comment: Oof... Well that definitely helped! But the value it's pulling is correct for some rows and incorrect for others. And I tried creating a Dim for the Yearly Change value and then resetting it to 0 at the end of the loop but still not correcting all of them.

Comment: I think the issue now is some of the tickers overlap. So ticker: "A" is being mistaken with ticker: "AA" and pulling the wrong value into the change function. Is there a way to make it match exact values?

Comment: LookAt:=xlWhole

Comment: The `LookAt` paramater of `Range.Find` defaults to `xlPart`, so it's only searching for a partial match. You'll always want to specify `LookAt:=xlWhole` for exact matches.

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Comment: @TateGarringer Problem solved should be followed by "Answer Accepted"..lol